# How to copy in additional files during "terraform get" that reside outside of the module directory?

Tags: terraform

The [Hashicorp Consul repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/tree/master/terraform/aws) contains a Terraform module for launching a Consul cluster in AWS. The module references several files that are found in the parent directory of the module under the `shared/scripts` directory here https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/tree/master/terraform

However, when I reference the module in one of my .tf files and run `terraform get` to download the module, the required files under `shared/scripts/` are not included with the downloaded module files, leading to errors like the one described [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/3518)

My `module` section in Terraform looks like this:

```
module "consul" {
  source = "github.com/hashicorp/consul/terraform/aws"

  key_name = "example_key"
  key_path = "/path/to/example_key"
  region   = "us-east-1"
  servers  = "3"
  platform = "centos7"
}
```

Is there anyway to have `terraform get` pull in files that live outside the module directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From looking at what those files do, I'd just copy the one's you need (depending on whether you're deploying on debian or rhel), which will be 2/3 files and feeding them into provisioner "file":

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html

Comment: I can manually copy them to my local Terraform workspace fine, what I'm wondering is if there is a way to have terraform do that copy automatically on `terraform get` even though those files are outside the `aws` module directory.